# Pandoc converting HTML tables to PDF results in non-wrapped tables

Tags: pandoc

I have some HTML tables that when rendered with a browser look normally wrapped. But when I try convert to pdf using `pdftex`, the tables are cutoff at the margins and are not wrapped. How do I make pandoc wrap the HTML tables?

Not the same as the markdown problem. The tables are pure html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that LaTeX requires explicit specification of column widths if you want the cells to wrap, so you need to manually specify those somehow (in markdown you would [do this using multiline or grid tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037357/pandoc-long-tablerows-in-markdown-pdf-documents-do-not-get-linewrap)).

Pandoc's HTML Reader supports relative `width` attributes on `col` elements.

```
pandoc -f html -t latex << EOF
> <table>
>   <colgroup>
>     <col width="10%">
>     <col width="90%">
>   </colgroup>
>   <tr>
>     <td>3476896</td>
>     <td>My first HTML</td>
>   </tr>
> </table>
> 
> EOF

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.09\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
3476896
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.85\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
My first HTML
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

Notice the `\columnwidth` in the LaTeX output.

If you have no control over the HTML, you can write a [Pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) that modifies the document's AST and sets some arbitrary column widths that add up to 100%. Maybe you should also revive [this old thread on pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pandoc-discuss/p83-LS9f34s/KjRSgvPCGxgJ) where jgm aka fiddlosopher wrote:

> The main reason is that with more complex tables, 
>   we need information about relative column widths, 
>   which the HTML document lacks.  But I think I'm 
>   becoming convinced that we should just guess at these.

Or file a [feature request](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues) to request this.

Comment: I guess that's it! But how would you apply this if you don't have control over the HTML? That is, the HTML is scraped?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Even if you're not the one who generates it, you always have control over the HTML -- it's text that you're free to edit. You can use e.g., Python's BeautifulSoup library to edit various aspects of the HTML.