# Pandoc: Long tablerows in mediwiki->PDF documents do not get linewrap

Tags: mediawiki, pandoc, tex

I am using Pandoc to generate Wiki ->DOCX

**My wiki file is**

```
=Graph Shared With (3)=
{| class="wikitable"
|-
| '''ID''' 
| '''Name''' 
|-
|115 sirajTest ahmad sirajTestsirajTest ahmad sirajTest
|sirajTest ahmad sirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmad
|-
|15 sirajTest ahmad sirajTest
|Test Marquard sirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmad
|-
|92sirajTest ahmad sirajTestsirajTest ahmad sirajTestsirajTest ahmad sirajTest
|Ahtesham ul haqsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmad
|}
```

and the output is 
[image]

In DOCX, long rows with text are simply broken up into multiple lines. In the PDF document this does not happen; a row is always a single line that do not wrap at the right margin but continue outside of the page

i am using Tex file as a template  and in that we have

```
 $if(tables)$
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,multirow}
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
$endif$
```

i tried to add multirow package but i dont think i am doing it correctly

there is one question in stack overflow similar to this but it is using markdown table but i am using media wiki table so its diffrent

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037357/pandoc-long-tablerows-in-markdown-pdf-documents-do-not-get-linewrap)

I think with multi row i can fix this but i do not know how :)
so is there any help or any one can guide me how can i solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify column widths, like:

```
{| class="wikitable"
! width="30%" | '''ID''' 
! width="70%" | '''Name''' 
|-
|115 sirajTest ahmad sirajTestsirajTest ahmad sirajTest
|sirajTest ahmad sirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmad
|-
|15 sirajTest ahmad sirajTest
|Test Marquard sirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmadsirajTest ahmad
|}
```

Comment: Perfect. In latex output it become fractions of `\columnwidth`, you can exceed 100% for wider tables if you're careful. What got me is that this syntax is not [contemporary mediawiki table markup](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables)